# Set the width of the div until browser side

Tags: html, css

I begin with two examples:

13" macbook pro:
[image: macscreen]
21" philips monitor
[image: philipscreen]

Is it possible to set up full width for parent element with `position:fixed`, but for children elements set width until browser site, so in all sizes text would be until browser site or with max width.

CSS:

```
div#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 70px;
}

header#left-panel, header#right-panel{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    min-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

header#left-panel{
    width: 185px;
    position: fixed;
}

header#right-panel{
    /*width: 100%;*/ /*here is the problem*/
    left: 755px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="left-panel">
            <section id="contacts">
            </section>
        </header>
        <header id="right-panel">
            <section id="comments">
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
                <div style="float:right">Lorem ipsum</div>
            </section>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `right:0` on the `header#right-panel` element.

You can play around with it on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/Vk8Ty/5/).

Answer (score 0):

```
header#right-panel{
    /*width: 100%;*/ 
    right: -1px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

should work